# Getting a null return from a GetUserManager call when using AspNet.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I have attempted to go through a few examples of utilizing Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and Microsoft.Asp.Identity.Owin all within WebForms. I have been able to create the database tables within my current database (I choose to keep both the AspNet tables from the User, Stores and Roles Manager in the same database as my application) and have the Model, Controller, View and App_Start folders in place with the needed files.

The line I am having issues with is in my code behind file for ForgetPassword in the Account folder: var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager();

Here is how I have the files set up:
**App_Start: IdentityConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using FHSF_4_DEV.Models;

namespace FHSF_4_DEV
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) :
            base(userManager, authenticationManager) { }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

**App_Start: Startup.Auth.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Owin;
using FHSF_4_DEV.Models;

namespace FHSF_4_DEV
{
    public partial class App_Start_Startup {

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301883
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("~/Default.aspx"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //   consumerKey: "",
            //   consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //   appId: "",
            //   appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            //{
            //    ClientId = "",
            //    ClientSecret = ""
            //});
        }
    }
}
```

***Account: ForgotPassword.aspx***

```
<%@ Page Title="Forgot password" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ForgotPassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="FHSF_4_DEV.Account.ForgotPassword" Async="true" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div style="width: 20%; text-align: center; color: white; margin-left: 40%; margin-right: 40%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="loginForm" runat="server">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <h2>Forgot your password?</h2>
                        <hr />
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" Visible="false">
                            <p class="text-danger">
                                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
                            </p>
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                        <div class="form-group" style="align-content:center">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Email</asp:Label>
                            <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-left:28%; margin-right:28%;">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Email" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Forgot" Text="Email Link" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="DisplayEmail" Visible="false">
                    <p class="text-info">
                        Please check your email to reset your password.
                    </p>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

***Account: ForgotPassword.aspx.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using FHSF_4_DEV.Models;
using SendGrid;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using FHSF_4_DEV;

namespace FHSF_4_DEV.Account
{
    public partial class ForgotPassword : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Forgot(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                // Validate the user's email address
                var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                ApplicationUser user = manager.FindByName(Email.Text);
                if (user == null || !manager.IsEmailConfirmed(user.Id))
                {
                    FailureText.Text = "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.";
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send email with the code and the redirect to reset password page
                string code = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
                string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetResetPasswordRedirectUrl(code, Request);
                manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");
                loginForm.Visible = false;
                DisplayEmail.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like I have things set up as they are needed, but my return from the var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager();
Line in ForgotPassword.aspx.cs is null, even though I have a user set up in the AspNetUser table.

Any help on leading me to why I am getting a null value and how I can get the correct reference would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the right context in the ForgotPassword.aspx.cs - like it should be small context (instance of IOwinContext) injected somehow in that page. Are you getting the owin context / corresponding db context for you to get application user manager?

Comment: I will do some digging to better understand and will provide my response at that time.

Comment: I tested to see if the process ever got to Startup.Auth,cs or IdentityConfig.cs and found out that it did not. Therefore, as I am implementing this in a non-MVC, non-CORE WebForms framework, I will move the classes in my Default.aspx.cs file. I'm just concerned that this will cause issues later, but not sure I have a choice.

Comment: This issue has morphed into another question which can be followed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717936/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-using-webforms