# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model : Using Webforms

Tags: c#, webforms, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I have reviewed several answers to this on StackOverflow, and I have applied and compared with no answer to my particular case. Here is what I have up to this point:

*****In Web.Config*****

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-2UA8GL6L\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FHSF_DEV;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

in IdentityModels.cs

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public int    UserDetailID { get; set; }

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

}

In IdentityConfig.cs

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

// Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }


        public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }


    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }


    //////// Commented out the rest of the code within this class //////
```

public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore(context.Get()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

```
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        //manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        //{
        //    MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        //});
        //manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        //{
        //    Subject = "Security Code",
        //    BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        //});

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = false;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

And, in the calling program where the error takes place

```
            if (IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the user's email address
            //var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            //ApplicationUser user = manager.FindByName(Email.Text);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            //var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
            //IdentityUser user = userManager.FindByEmail(Email.Text);

            var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("FHSFReset");
            ApplicationDbContext context = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // The error occurs below /////////////////////////////////
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByEmail(Email.Text);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Error msg: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity 
            //  type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the 
            //  current context.'
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            if (user == null)
            {
                FailureText.Text = "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send email with the code and the redirect to reset password page
            userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
                provider.Create("EmailRestPW"));
```

NOTE: I am utilizing Identity, Entity Framework (I think) and OWIN. I am attempting to keep the Authorization/Authentication tables within my database and the tables are there. I (as is shown above) have added customized fields in AspNetUsers and should be reflected in the connectivity.

Is there anything apparent that indicates I have set this up incorrectly such that the error is occurring?

Comment: Very hard to see what's going on but in `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));` - it looks like you're trying to use the EF context to get the `ApplicationUser` but that's not part of the context, hence the error.

Comment: I wonder if I'm mixing how I approach to accessing the security data (The AspNet files), and if that is where I am going wrong. I have OWIN and EntityFramework together, and I have the customized fields set up. I thought the only way to achieve that would be with EF, but that I also needed OWIN if I wanted to go with other social networking signins in the future. Should I get rid of the OWIN references and try to correctly set up the EF context to include the ApplicationUser so that I can access the custom fields?

Comment: I inserted the code as you suggested in the IdentityConfig.cs file. Still got the same error.

Comment: Please see that the code change is reflected in the original post.